# How to make ScalarEvolution recompute SCEV values?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing a loop pass for LLVM. I clone and rearrange loops, which can be done multiple times. 
The trouble is, after the first time I do this, the SCEVs become `SCEVUnknown` types when they should be `SCEVAddRecExpr`.

However, if I re-run the whole pass using the first iteration's output, it will correctly identify them as `SCEVAddRecExpr`.

I've already tried called Scalar Evolution's `ForgetAllLoops` function, but that doesn't work. I also tried calling the `runOnFuction` from the ScalarEvolution pass, but that also didn't work.

My question is: is there a way to re-run an analysis pass during my pass? Or how can I make ScalarEvolution re-calculate the SCEV values for the unknown SCEVs.

Comment: If you're using the new pass manager, your `run()` returns what it [preserves](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PreservedAnalyses.html), so `return PreservedAnalyses::none();` will do as a start.

Comment: @arnt I’m pretty new to LLVM. Is there a way to do that using the old pass manager?

Comment: Perhaps. I vaguely remember something like that... But when I was new to LLVM and had a problem, I quickly learned that fixing stuff based on the legacy pass manager was painting myself into a corner. The maintainers didn't replace the old one (and rename it "legacy") without reason.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll look into using the new pass manager